# Unable to start the MGT Development Environment

Tags: magento

I'm trying to setup the MGT Development Environment [as per the instructions on the site](https://www.mgt-commerce.com/documentation/mgt-development-environment-run-container). I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and native docker.

I did a fresh pull before trying any of this. After running the container the browser at 127.0.0.1:3333 just shows the general HTTP 500 error. Running docker logs on the container shows the following log entries:

```
    docker logs 7b1f04c29bf2
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2017-03-28 14:03:53,908 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-03-28 14:03:53,908 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2017-03-28 14:03:53,916 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-03-28 14:03:53,917 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-03-28 14:03:53,917 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2017-03-28 14:03:54,919 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 9
2017-03-28 14:03:54,920 INFO spawned: 'postfix' with pid 10
2017-03-28 14:03:54,922 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 11
2017-03-28 14:03:54,928 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 13
2017-03-28 14:03:54,930 INFO spawned: 'varnish' with pid 16
2017-03-28 14:03:54,932 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 18
2017-03-28 14:03:54,934 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 19
2017-03-28 14:03:54,935 INFO spawned: 'clp-server' with pid 20
2017-03-28 14:03:54,937 INFO spawned: 'clp5-fpm' with pid 23
2017-03-28 14:03:54,938 INFO spawned: 'mysql' with pid 24
2017-03-28 14:03:54,940 INFO spawned: 'memcached' with pid 26
2017-03-28 14:03:54,940 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:54,941 INFO success: postfix entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:55,011 INFO exited: mysql (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:55,102 INFO exited: postfix (exit status 0; expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:55,255 INFO exited: varnish (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,256 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,257 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,259 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 382
2017-03-28 14:03:56,262 INFO spawned: 'varnish' with pid 383
2017-03-28 14:03:56,263 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,263 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,263 INFO success: clp-server entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,263 INFO success: clp5-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,266 INFO spawned: 'mysql' with pid 384
2017-03-28 14:03:56,266 INFO success: memcached entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,279 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,279 CRIT reaped unknown pid 385)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,306 INFO exited: mysql (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:56,585 INFO exited: varnish (exit status 2; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:58,588 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 396
2017-03-28 14:03:58,589 INFO spawned: 'varnish' with pid 397
2017-03-28 14:03:58,590 INFO spawned: 'mysql' with pid 398
2017-03-28 14:03:58,599 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:58,605 CRIT reaped unknown pid 399)
2017-03-28 14:03:58,632 INFO exited: mysql (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:03:58,913 INFO exited: varnish (exit status 2; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:04:01,919 INFO spawned: 'redis' with pid 410
2017-03-28 14:04:01,921 INFO spawned: 'varnish' with pid 411
2017-03-28 14:04:01,923 INFO spawned: 'mysql' with pid 412
2017-03-28 14:04:01,930 INFO exited: redis (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:04:01,930 INFO gave up: redis entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2017-03-28 14:04:01,930 CRIT reaped unknown pid 413)
2017-03-28 14:04:01,969 INFO exited: mysql (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:04:02,238 INFO gave up: mysql entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2017-03-28 14:04:02,238 INFO exited: varnish (exit status 2; not expected)
2017-03-28 14:04:03,240 INFO gave up: varnish entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

If I logon to the container via docker exec -it bash it shows the following running process:

```
root@mgt-dev-70:/# ps -aux    
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.1  48144 16348 ?        Ss+  14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root         9  0.0  0.0  55600  5268 ?        S    14:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root        11  0.0  0.3 819816 49984 ?        S    14:03   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)           
root        18  0.0  0.0  25904  2236 ?        S    14:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root        19  0.0  0.1  64660 23456 ?        S    14:03   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon off;
root        20  0.0  0.0  93752  8432 ?        S    14:03   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/clp-server -g daemon off;
root        23  0.0  0.2 854428 39528 ?        S    14:03   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/clp5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)         
root        25  0.1  0.0  37256  8876 ?        Ssl  14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379       
memcache    26  0.0  0.0 327452  2724 ?        Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -p 11211 -u memcache -m 256 -c 1024
root        40  0.0  0.1  65564 21516 ?        S    14:03   0:00 nginx: worker process         
root       102  0.0  0.0  94588  4304 ?        S    14:03   0:00 nginx: worker process              
root       156  0.0  0.0  36620  3948 ?        Ss   14:03   0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
postfix    157  0.0  0.0  38684  3780 ?        S    14:03   0:00 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
postfix    158  0.0  0.0  38732  3892 ?        S    14:03   0:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
varnish    164  0.0  0.0 126924  7172 ?        Ss   14:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T :6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m
vcache     165  0.0  0.7 314848 123484 ?       Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T :6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m
root       495  0.0  0.0  20244  2984 ?        Ss   14:12   0:00 bash
root       501  0.0  0.0  17500  2036 ?        R+   14:12   0:00 ps -aux
```

That's really as much as I know.  Any guideance on getting it progressed appreciated as it looks great as a quick and easy way to get going on Magento 2. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity Just following the guidance on the support site btw. See  [link] https://www.mgt-commerce.com/documentation/mgt-development-environment-support

Comment: I appreciate that, but they have done a wrong thing there. Stack Overflow's help specifically says that the following is on-topic - "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Otherwise it is off-topic.